# Problema con return Javascript

Tags: javascript

Siempre he tenido poca claridad en como 'recoger' o 'captar' el valor del return, sé que es con expresiones funcionales, pero cómo ?

Mi intento:

```js
var calc = document.getElementById('gosqrt');
calc.addEventListener("click", maths);

function maths() {
  
  var b = document.getElementById("sqrt").value;
  //alert(Math.sqrt(b));
    return Math.sqrt(b);
  
}

var um = maths();

document.write(um);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="sqrt" placeholder="Square root"/>
  <input type="button" id="gosqrt" value="Calcular"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Analisis**

Si observamos el codigo, podemos encontrarnos con la siguiente linea:

```
calc.addEventListener("click", maths);
```

Esta le asigna un *listener* al elemento `calc`, pero ***¿Que quiere decir esto?***

Cuando se haga **clic** al elemento `calc`, este ejecutara una funcion.

**¿Donde esta el problema?**

El **problema** viene a darse en el hecho, en que **no estamos guardando** el resultado retornado de esa funcion en ninguna parte.

Tenemos esta linea:

```
var um = maths();
document.write(um);
```

Simplemente **ejecuta** la funcion `maths()`, y listo, el `valor` retornado de la funcion `maths()` se asigna a la variable `um` y se imprime el valor...No pasa nada mas.

**¿Porque no nos funciona el boton?**

Solo hemos asignado el *listener*, mas **no hemos asignado el resultado** de la funcion a algun elemento.

**¿Como podriamos solucionarlo?**

Una solucion podria ser esta:

```js
/* Asignamos el listener */
var calc = document.getElementById('gosqrt');
calc.addEventListener("click", botonPresionado);

/* Creamos una variable que contendra el resultado */
var resultado;

/**
 * Funcion maths()
 * Calcula la raiz cuadrada
 */
function calcularRaiz() {  
  var b = document.getElementById("sqrt").value;  
  return Math.sqrt(b);  
}

/**
 * Funcion botonPresionado()
 * Funcion a ejecutar cuando se presione el boton
 */
function botonPresionado() {  
  resultado = calcularRaiz();
  alert(resultado);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="sqrt" placeholder="Square root"/>
  <input type="button" id="gosqrt" value="Calcular"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**¿Que hemos hecho aca?**

Creamos una *variable global*, llamada `resultado` y en ella guardamos el resultado de la funcion `calcularRaiz()` *(anterior maths())*, y ejecutamos un `alert()`, para **mostrar** el resultado de la operacion.